# STL sort doesn't sort my vector<pair<int,int> > well

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

I am trying to solve a more complex algorithmic problem and a partial requirement involves sorting some pairs of integers.

Here is my code ( I've commented the irellevant part for my question)

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

ifstream fin("ai.in");
ofstream fout("ai.out");

#define MaxN 1001
#define MaxK 150001
//
//int n;
//int t1, t2, s1, s2, s3, s4, r1, r2, r3, r4;
int k;
int x,y;

vector<pair<int,int> >v(MaxK);

int main()
{
//    fin >> n;
//
//    fin >> t1 >> t2 >> s1 >> s2 >> s3 >> s4 >> r1 >> r2 >> r3 >> r4;

    fin >> k;

    for ( int i = 1; i <= k; ++i )
    {
        fin >> x >> y;
        v[i].first = x;
        v[i].second = y;
    }

    sort(v.begin() + 1, v.begin() + n + 1);

    for ( int i = 1; i <= k; ++i, fout << '\n' )
        fout << v[i].first << ' ' << v[i].second;

    fin.close();
    fout.close();
    return 0;
}
```

For this input

```
8
1 2
2 3
2 5
4 2
6 2
2 2
2 4
5 2
```

I get this output

```
1 2
2 2
2 3
2 5
4 2
6 2
2 4
5 2
```

Which of course is wrong as you can see the 2 4 pair near the end of output.
So how can I solve this?

Comment: Does not compile: line `sort(v.begin() + 1, v.begin() + n + 1);` `n: undefined identifier`.

Comment: `std::sort(v.begin(), v.end())`. What does that mean? Try reading it as English. it "sort"s from "begin" to "end". It's that simple. `v.begin() + 1` is trivially a different thing than `v.begin()`.

Comment: Oops, I typed n instead of k. Now everything works. Thanks.

Comment: Just free advice: find a bug in your code before thinking STL or any other library is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of the program

```
fin >> k;

for ( int i = 1; i <= k; ++i )
{
    fin >> x >> y;
    v[i].first = x;
    v[i].second = y;
}

sort(v.begin() + 1, v.begin() + n + 1);
```

where it is not clear what variable `n` means

Should look the following way

```
fin >> k;

if ( MaxK < k ) k = MaxK;

for ( int i 0 1; i < k; ++i )
{
    fin >> x >> y;
    v[i].first = x;
    v[i].second = y;
}

sort( v.begin(), v.begin() + k );
```

The last statement can bewriten also like

```
sort( v.begin(), std::next( v.begin(), k ) );
```

provided that header `<iterator>` will be included

You may set also the range like [1, k + 1 ) but from your post it is not clear why the frist element of the vector should not be filled.

It seems that you get an unexpected result due to setting invalid upper bound of the range.

Answer (score 0):

You probably provide wrong `end` iterator to sort, as you can see last two entries from your input are the same as in output - sort simply does not include them in sorting.

`std::sort` will sort pairs, first by first element - and if both are equal it will compare second.